# Embedded mongoid document not marked as dirty / not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mongoid, activemodel

I have a data model as follows

- A bid is associated with the `User` that placed the bid
- A bid may be either an `offer` or a `listing` on a single `Product`
- A `Product` may have multiple offers and listings (separate) posted by multiple users
- A user may place offers and listings on multiple `Products`

Product <--- Bid ---> User

Given an existing `p` from the `Product` model, operations like `p.offers << bid` where `bid` is a new instance of the `Bid` class do not mark `p` as "dirty" and changes are not persisted to the database

Product class

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  embeds_many :offers, class_name: 'Bid'
  embeds_many :listings, class_name: 'Bid'
end
```

Bid class

```
class Bid
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  field :amount, type: Money  
  field :timestamp, type: DateTime, default: ->{ Time.now }
end
```

Additionally, calling `bid.save!` or creating a new array `p.offers = Array.new [bid]` do not seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Your model structure should be

```
class Product
   include Mongoid::Document
   ...
   has_many :offers, class_name: 'Bid', :inverse_of => :offers_bid
   has_many :listings, class_name: 'Bid', :inverse_of => :listings_bid
end

class Bid
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :offers_bid, :class_name => 'Product', :inverse_of => :offers
   belongs_to :listings_bid, :class_name => 'Product', :inverse_of => :listings
   belongs_to :user

   field :amount, type: Money  
   field :timestamp, type: DateTime, default: ->{ Time.now }
end
```

Comment: So if a bid is 'owned by' a user, should I just use a has_one(on bid) and has_many(on the user) relationship then?

Comment: updated the answer...sorry for the last incomplete answer. Try the present updated one

Comment: Hey! I think this works a lot better. Only thing is that you can add a bid as both a offer and a listing (is there any way to prevent that?) Otherwise, working well!